# XMLAccess in WebSpherePortal 6.1?

Tags: websphere-6.1

Hi I want to install and configure new theme and skin the WebSpherePortal server 6.1.
Any one give reference or document for this xmlaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Configuring the themes and skins we have to copy our themes into file:\$server_root$\installedApps\IBM-710BB15A391\wps.ear\wps.war\themes\html
and skin into 
file:\$server_root$\installedApps\IBM-710BB15A391\wps.ear\wps.war\skins\html
For Skin:
1)Register the skin

RegisterSkin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_6.1.0.xsd"
type="update" create-oids="true">
 <portal action="locate">
<skin action="update" active="true" objectid="rockskin" uniquename="rockskin"
   resourceroot="w3skin"> 
     <localedata locale="en"> 
     <title>rockskin</title> 
    </localedata> 
 </skin> 
</portal>
</request>
```

->xmlaccess.bat –in RegisterSkin.xml -out  -user usrname  –pwd password   –url http://localhost:10040/wps/config

2)Register the theme

i)Register the theme with existed skin
 RegisterTheme1.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_6.1.0.xsd"
type="update" create-oids="true">
<portal action="locate">
  <skin action=”locate” active=”true” objectid=”noSkin” 
  uniquename=”wps.skin.noSkin”/>
  <theme action="update" active="true" defaultskinref="noSkin "
   uniquename="rocktheme" resourceroot="w3theme">
    <localedata locale="en">
    <title>Rock Theme</title>
    </localedata>
   <allowed-skin skin=" noSkin" update="set"/>
 </theme>
</portal>
</request>
```

->xmlaccess.bat –in RegisterTheme1.xml -out  -user usrname  –pwd password   –url http://localhost:10040/wps/config

ii)Register the theme with new skin
In the above xml file we are using the existed skin name noSkin
If you want to apply new skin you have to mention as follows:

RegisterTheme2.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_6.1.0.xsd"
type="update" create-oids="true">
<portal action="locate">
   <skin action="update" active="true" objectid="newSkin" 
    uniquename="newSkin " resourceroot="newSkin "> 
      <localedata locale="en"> 
      <title>rockskin</title> 
      </localedata> 
   </skin> 
  <theme action="update" active="true" defaultskinref="newSkin " uniquename=" 
   w3theme " resourceroot="w3theme">
     <localedata locale="en">
     <title>Rock Theme</title>
     </localedata>
     <allowed-skin skin="newSkin " update="set"/>
  </theme>
</portal>
</request>
```

->xmlaccess.bat –in RegisterTheme2.xml -out  -user usrname  –pwd password   –url http://localhost:10040/wps/config

Note:resourceroot in the both skin and theme must be your copied theme and skin folder names.

Comment: I have done R & D on the XMLACCESS for Configuring theme and skin including other concepts aslo.I have tested in my system and it's working fine.So that i think i shold post.